# A way to rename keep the first 10 charaters of a image name

Tags: windows, images, rename

I have a very big job to do.

I have about 930 pictures which are called like:

- 5210841 Tuinset Senator.jpg
- 5210898 Traptrede Premium.jpg

etc.

I'm looking for a way to rename these pictures, without losing the number part.

So for the first one, its name would be:

- 5210841.jpg

and the second

- 5210898.jpg

Can you guys think about a program which can do this job?

It's for a Windows platform.

Comment: it's for windows

Comment: Found it, File Renamer Basic does the job, You can choose from which character you want to delete the rest. I set it from 8 to 255

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**Total Commander**](http://www.ghisler.com) - it's shareware (but the only limitation is a nag screen at startup). It has a very powerful batch rename option and is a great file manager overall.

Answer (score 5):

As long as all the numbers are the same amount of digits like the example then the standard Windows rename should do it:

```
C:\FolderOfPictures>ren *.jpg ???????.*
```

If you need the first 10 characters like the question title, use 10 question marks.  One for each character you want to keep. :)

Answer (score 0):

With the rename utility you can do:

```
rename 's/^(\d*)(.*)\.jpg/$1.jpg/' *.jpg
```

Don't know whether this exists on windows though.

Answer (score 0):

Found it, File Renamer Basic does the job, You can choose from which character you want to delete the rest. I set it from 8 to 255